# Reading Excel with merged cells, forms controls, password protected sheets

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I need to read an Excel 2003 spreadsheet that is from the gov't HHS dept. The XLS has merged cells, password protected macros and form controls (eg, buttons, drop downs).

Here are the requirements:

I need to pragmatically read this on a server that does not have Excel installed on it.

I can't use OLE 4 driver since it has issues with merged cells, data is dropped. Or maybe something else like the form controls is throwing it off.

Excel stops me from saving password protected spreadsheets as XML and we won't have the password.

I tried to use Excel 2007 and 2010 to save it as XLSX and use the ACE OLE Excel driver. Merged cells doesn't seem to be an issue, but the form controls are (maybe that was really the case using the JET driver, too).

I tried a sample project on CodeProject that reads the native BIFF format and it worked OK with 2003, but choked on 2007 and 2010 and we are likely to upgrade soon, so I don't want to plan it being obsolete soon.

Is there perhaps a good, reliable corporate liability-friendly open source library for reading the native XLS format that might read this spreadsheet or do I have to decide whether I need to convince my manager that we either need to purchase a 3rd party product or get a pita corporate exception  to install Excel on a server.  The former is the preferred approach if there are no other options.

What's my best option or what would be a good reliable 3rd party library?

Thx

Comment: if removing the password allows you to save as XML and that's enough for you, take a look here: [link](http://mcgimpsey.com/excel/removepwords.html)

Comment: Incidentally, I was able to remove the password but I don't think this will be a solution for me. Besides possible legal issues, I need to use the EXCEL API to remove the password and that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: In the past I used [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). It's open source and was enough for my needs.

Comment: When I tried Gembox I got the error: Current version of GemBox.Spreadsheet can't read encrypted workbooks. You can use only simple password protection against modifying (set in MS Excel 'Save As' dialog). 
It looks to me like GEMBOX doesn't support reading password protected sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you need, but if you use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) (not Gembox) you can read AND modify protected workbooks and save them. For instance you can try soimething like this to read the value of A1 cell, modify the value of D4 and save the result. This work even if the workbook is protected (you can't modify x.xls using Excel).

```
        string fullPath = @"c:\tmp\x.xls";
        FileStream aFile = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(aFile);
        aFile.Close();
        ISheet curSheet = wb.GetSheet("Foglio1");
        IRow aRow = curSheet.GetRow(0);
        if (aRow == null)
            aRow = curSheet.CreateRow(0);
        ICell aCell = aRow.GetCell(0);
        if (aCell == null)
            aCell = aRow.CreateCell(0);
        MessageBox.Show(aCell.StringCellValue);
        aRow = curSheet.GetRow(3);
        if (aRow == null)
            aRow = curSheet.CreateRow(3);
        aCell = aRow.GetCell(3);
        if (aCell == null)
            aCell = aRow.CreateCell(3);
        aCell.SetCellValue("testValue");
        fullPath = @"c:\tmp\x2.xls";
        File.Delete(fullPath);
        aFile = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create);
        wb.Write(aFile);
        aFile.Close();
```

Unfortunately there is no way to unprotect a sheet using NPOI (at least not a way that I'm aware of), but you can set the password to whatever you want, even without knowing the original password. It's as simple as:

```
curSheet.ProtectSheet(string.Empty);
```